# How to parse the array from one activity to fragment in android?

Tags: android, arrays, parsing, android-fragments

I am bulding an android application where an user select There
 favorite stuff.

The name of stuff is added in an array by clicking on Image of this
 stuff.

Now I need is that how can I parse the value of that array to any
 fragment and show in my spinner list.

For example like user select Mobile and tablet by click there image
 this value add in an array name stuffarray now I need is that this
 array value pass to my fragment on an submitted button and when I
 click on an spinner of my fragment it Should have mobile and tablet value in there
 list.

Here is my code for stuff selection :

```
submite = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextscreen);      
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent innext = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivitytabnew.class);

            startActivity(innext);              

    });


   img1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);


    img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mobile);   
    img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             isClicked1=!isClicked1;
                if (isClicked1) {
                    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.mobile);
                    start();
                    stuff1 = "mobile";

                       myList.add(stuff1);



                }else {
                    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.mobile);
                    myList.remove(sport1);
                    //sport1 = "";  
                    txt1.setText("");
                }
        }
    });

    img2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    img2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tablet);
    img2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            isClicked2=!isClicked2;
            if (isClicked2) {
                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.tablet);
                start();
                stuff2 = "tablet";
               myList.add(stuff2);
            }else {
                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.tablet);
               // sport2 = "";
                myList.remove(sport2);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: post some code about your data structure

Comment: @bladefury ok I am editing my question with my code

Comment: @bladefury Thanks I had edit my ques as per your requirement

Comment: use sharedprefrencea

Comment: How can I use it please can you tell me with an example as I am new to this sharedprefrencea.

Comment: To pass data from the activity to a fragment you should be using setArguments http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: @eduyayo thanks I had send data from put method but how to get it in fragment there is an problem. How to get the array value can you please help in this

Comment: If u see the examples in the link: `getArguments()`

Comment: @eduyayo yes men I had read it but the value are not coming in my array when I toast the value of it can you please guide me as might be I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

seems that your are passing `List<String>` to fragment.

You should use `Bundle` to hold your data and then pass to fragment use `Fragment.setArguments`.

here is a example:

```
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putStringArrayList("your_argument_name", dataList);
    Fragment f = ...;
    f.setArguments(data);
```

here is how to read value in your fragment's code, like in onCreateView :

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle data = getArguments();
        if (data != null) {
            List<String> dataList = data.getStringArrayList("yout_argument_name");
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks what is Fragment f = ...; here please can you tell me

Comment: @HiteshMatnani I read your code, is `MainActivitytabnew` the class that you hope to receive your list?

Comment: It is an main activity where I had code the fragment. So I should right here fragment class name.... am I right ?

Comment: @HiteshMatnani so your should first pass data to main activity, and then pass to fragment use the code above.Fragment f = ...; is where you get your fragment instance

Comment: You mean that First parse the value to mainactivity and then again parse the value to fragment

Comment: Still it is showing an error - MainActivitytabnew cannot be resolved to a variable